# Extract info from one table based on data from antoher

Tags: sql

I am kind of new to SQL and I made a couple of tables to practice. The columns may have some unrelated categories but I don't know what else write...

Anyway, basically what i want to do is get info from two tables based on the first and last name from one table.

Here are my tables:

Order
[image: Order]

Host
[image: Cost]

I want create a query to pull the ticket number, height, order, subtotal and total by first and last name. The only orders I want to pull are from John Smith And Sam Ting. So in the end, I want my extraction to have the following columns:

- Ticket Number
- First Name
- Last Name
- Height
- Order
- Subtotal
- Total

Any help or direction would be awesome!

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: Sounds like a simple query with a `JOIN`. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the assumption the tables both have unique Ticket_Numbers and that will provide a one-to-one mapping between then.

```
SELECT 
    Order.Ticket_Number, 
    First_Name,
    Last_Name,
    Height,
    Order,
    Subtotal,
    Total
FROM Order
JOIN Host on Host.Ticket_Number = Order.Ticket_Number
WHERE 
    (First_Name = 'John' AND  Last_Name = 'Smith')
    OR (First_Name = 'Sam' AND  Last_Name = 'Ting')
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the help. Since I want only tickets from John Smith and Sam Ting, don't I need a WHERE Syntax? If so, how and where do you add that to the query? Thanks for the help again

Comment: Missed that initially in the description.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try on my laptop tomorrow and get back to you if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to "call" the table name first, and then the column. After that you need to use the "join" for the 2 tables. And finally you need the "where". I didn't look for the details so you need to check the "names".

```
SELECT Order.Ticket_Number, Order.First_Name, Order.Last_Name, Order.Height, Order.Order, Cost.Subtotal, Cost.Total
FROM Order
INNER JOIN Cost
where First_Name="Jhon" and Last_Name="blablabla"
or
First_Name="SecondGuy" and Last_Name="blablabla"
```